# jQuery Sortable - Limit number of items in list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, limit, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a schedule table I'm using jQuery Sortable for editing.

Each day is a UL, and each event is an LI.

My jQuery is:

```
    $("#colSun, #colMon, #colTue, #colWed, #colThu").sortable({
         connectWith: '.timePieces',
         items: 'li:not(.lith)'
    }).disableSelection();
```

To make all LI's sortable except those with class "lith" (day names).
User can drag an event from day to day, or add new events by clicking a button, which appends a new draggable event (LI) to the fist UL (Sunday).

I want to make each day accept only up to 10 events.
How do I do this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> - **DEMO:** http://so.lucafilosofi.com/jquery-sortable-limit-number-of-items-in-list

```
$(function() {
    $(".sortables").sortable({
        connectWith: '.connectedSortable',
        //receive: This event is triggered when a
        //connected sortable list has received an item from another list.
        receive: function(event, ui) {
            // so if > 10
            if ($(this).children().length > 10) {
                //ui.sender: will cancel the change.
                //Useful in the 'receive' callback.
                $(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');
            }
        }
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

Comment: This is great, thanks!

One tiny problem - it does not count elements added dynamically - i.e. it counts how mani items are in the UL when the page loads, and if I delete items it does not recalculate...

Any idea hiow to solve this?

Comment: I'm talking about the first methid of course (when dragging, not when adding an item).

Thanks

Comment: ok ok, i have understood! ;-) no problem, but, for make it work dinamically you need to reload the page via ajax using jquery as well!

Answer (score 11):

To have the function fire every time that you try to drag a new item into a specific list (dynamically) you need to use `on()` rather than the `receive:` method.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#event-receive

```
$(function() {
    $( "#day1, #day2" ).sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
    }).disableSelection();

    $( "#day1" ).on( "sortreceive", function(event, ui) {
        if($("#day1 li").length > 10){
            $(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');
        }
    });

});
```