# Limit number of items in sortable (with draggable as source)?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a draggable that is connected via `connectToSortable` to *multiple* sortables. I want to limit the number of items you can put in each sortable. I can do this when you drag from another sortable, but not when you drag from the draggable to the sortable. A simple example (as [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/owezam/4)):

```
$( ".sortable" ).sortable({
  connectWith: ".sortable"
});

$( ".sortable" ).bind( "sortreceive", function(event, ui) {
  // This will not work because the sender is a draggable, which has no "cancel" method
  if ( 4 < $( this ).sortable( 'toArray' ).length ) {
    $(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');
  }
});

$( "#draggable li" ).draggable({
  connectToSortable: ".sortable",
  helper: 'clone'
});
```

I first tried `$(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');` in the `sortreceive` event, but because the sender is a `draggable`, not another `sortable`, it does not have a `cancel` method and this does not work (so [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438516/jquery-sortable-limit-number-of-items-in-list) and [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539708/jquery-ui-draggable-sortable-droppable-disable-drop-when-droppable-limit-is-reach/3673837#3673837) questions don't seem to solve my problem). I have tried following [the logic that glues the draggable and the sortable together](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/1.8.12/ui/jquery.ui.draggable.js#L467), but I see no place to jump in and cancel the "faked" stop.

It would be great if there was some kind of visual feedback, like the mouse cursor changing to `no-drop`, and/or a background color change on the sortable.

Context: This is an attempt to answer [Limit number of Widgets in Sidebars](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19907/limit-number-of-widgets-in-sidebars) on the WordPress Stack Exchange. The WordPress widget administration page has a container with all available widgets set up as a draggable, connected to different sortable containers for each sidebar. I don't want to modify [the core code](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.2/wp-admin/js/widgets.dev.js#L72), just extend it with as little code as needed to prevent dropping another widget on a "full" sidebar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the if clause to check the number of elements in the sortable and unbind the draggable event when u have reached that number.

**EDIT: (Includes multiple list support now)**

```
$('.draggable').draggable({revert:true,helper:'clone',connectToSortable: '.sortable'});

$('.sortable').sortable({
    connectWith:'.sortable',
    receive: function(ui) {
        if($(this).children().length >=6) {
            $(this).children().addClass('filled');
            $(this).addClass('dontDrop');
            $('.sortable').sortable('option', 'connectWith',$('.sortable').not('.dontDrop'));
            $('.draggable').draggable('option', 'connectToSortable',$('.sortable').not('.dontDrop'));
        }else {
            $(this).children().removeClass('filled');
        }
        add_delete();
    }
});
function add_delete() {
    $('.delete').remove();
    $('.sortable>li').append('<span class="delete">--</span>');
    $('.delete').unbind('click').click(function(){
        if($(this).parent().siblings().length <=5) {//for atmost 6 children in sortable
            $(this).parent().parent().children().removeClass('filled');
            $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('dontDrop');
            console.log($('.sortable').not('.dontDrop'));
            $('.sortable').sortable('option', 'connectWith',$('.sortable').not('.dontDrop'));
            $('.draggable').draggable('option', 'connectToSortable',$('.sortable').not('.dontDrop'));
        }
        $(this).parent().hide('slow').remove();
    });
}
add_delete();
```

Check fiddle here [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VMKZV/1/)

So what I have used here is: One can pass not just selectors but elements themselves to the connectWith/connectToSortable options. Whenever an 'ul' has 6 elements I give it the class 'dontDrop' and it is hence excluded from the connections.
Hope this clears it out for you.

Let that bounty come this way :D

Comment: Thank you for this, but I was not clear enough that I'm talking about *multiple* sortables. So when one is full, you should still be able to drag to the other sortables. I have updated my question (and code example) to make this more clear.

Comment: Ah, this looks very promising! WordPress already has a "trash area" to drop items you want to remove, so I can leave out part of that. I will try it out in the actual context later today - or you can answer the original question yourself and earn rep on the WordPress Stack Exchange :-)

Comment: "Later today" became "later this week", but your solution was indeed what I needed! I will incorporate it into an answer on the original question, and make a reference to your effort.

Answer (score 4):

You could deactivate the connection when a condition is met:

```
$("#sortable").bind( "sortreceive", function(event, ui) {
    if ($( "#sortable li" ).length > 3){
        $( "#draggable li" ).draggable( "option", "connectToSortable", false );
    }
});
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZLCDr/1/

Comment: Thank you for this, but I was not clear enough that I'm talking about *multiple* sortables, so just removing the connection will break dragging to all sortables, not just the one that has too many options. I have updated my question and code example to make this clear.